# css style not executing

Tags: css, stylesheet

Hi I was just making some adjustments for on my web site. Everything was all good until I just checked it awhile ago and all my css styling does not seem to be working. when I went to my web-host and checked the file seemed to be fine. when i inspect the page from firefox the css code seems to be there but not working. when i check it from chrome i seems to should it as a empty file and also not working.

If any body has any idea why this is happening would be great thanks.

```html
.ui-widget INPUT {
    font-size: 11px !important;
    font-family: "Tahoma" !important;
}
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 8pt;
    background: #E8F6FD url('images/bg.jpg') repeat-x;
    align: center;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}
/* override default font */

.ui-widget {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
#mainwrapper {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid lightgray;
    /*background:url('images/page_bg.jpg') repeat-y;*/
    
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 30px;
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    background-image: url('images/footerbg.jpg');
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
    /* background:white;*/
    
    width: 900px;
    height: 620px;
}
#mainwrapperreg {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid lightgray;
    /*background:url('images/page_bg.jpg') repeat-y;*/
    
    margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
    background-image: url('images/footerbg.jpg');
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
    /* background:white;*/
    
    width: 900px;
    height: 375px;
}
#maintag {
    float: left;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding-left: 7px;
}
#mainleft {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 62%;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    margin-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}
#mainright {
    float: right;
    width: 35%;
    background-color: white;
}
#mainlogo {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
#mainbottom {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#mainfooter {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 20px;
}
#mainfooter a {
    color: white;
}
#mainfooter a:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
#msg {
    color: red;
}
#righttop {
    float: left;
    width: 95%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
#rightbottom {
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 95%;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
#rightbottom {} #rightbottom h1 {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.taglines {
    float: left;
    width: 22%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.taglines:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
.taglines h1 {
    font-size: 12pt;
}
.stairs h1 {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
.stairs {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 98%;
}
.stairs td {
    width: 25%;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
.stairsgrid {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
.stairsgridleft {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
#QuizSelection {
    border: 1px solid DarkGray;
    background-color: LightGray;
    text-align: left;
    width: 76%;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
}
#QuizSelection h1 {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
#QuizSelection li {
    display: block;
}
#QuizSelection li a {
    color: #165B8E;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
#QuizSelection li a:hover {
    background-color: DarkGray;
}
#divLinker {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100px;
}
#btnPerformanceImprovement_xxx {
    position: relative;
    top: 102px;
}
.tip {
    width: 300px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent url(images/tooltiptop.gif) no-repeat top;
}
.tipMid {
    background: transparent url(images/tooltipmid.gif) repeat-y;
    padding: 0 25px 20px 25px;
}
.tipBtm {
    background: transparent url(images/tooltipbottom.gif) no-repeat;
    height: 32px;
}
#productselection {
    height: 625px;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 970px;
    height: 720px;
    border: 2px solid lightgray;
    /*background:url('images/page_bg.jpg') repeat-y;*/
    
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 15px;
    /*background:white;*/
    
    background-image: url('images/footerbg.jpg');
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
}
#gsWrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid lightgray;
    width: 940px;
    background-image: url('images/footerbg.jpg');
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right bottom;
    /*background:url('images/page_bg.jpg') repeat-y;*/
    /*background:white;*/
    
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 15px;
}
#gsFooter {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url('images/footerbg.jpg') 10 0 no-repeat;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
#wrapper_home {
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 940px;
    background: url('images/page_bg.jpg') repeat-y;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 15px;
}
#homepage_top {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: url('images/top.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 940px;
}
#homepage_bottom {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: url('images/bottom.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 940px;
}
#tutorial {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 940px;
    height: 822px;
    background: black;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 15px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#gs {
    /* background:url('images/gsBg.png') no-repeat;*/
}
#bc {
    background: url('images/bcBg.jpg') no-repeat;
    */
}
.retailGS {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px solid black;
    margin-left: 70px;
    top: 200px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #165b8e;
}
.retailGS:a {
    color: #165b8e;
}
#topDiv_home {
    /*background:url('images/header.png') no-repeat;*/
    
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 938px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 28px;
}
#topDiv {
    /*background:url('images/header.jpg') no-repeat;*/
    
    height: 90px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 970px;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 28px;
}
#topDivLogoHome {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
#topDivLogo {
    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
#topDivLogoHome span {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    left: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
#header {
    color: #333;
    width: 900px;
    float: left;
    padding: 6px;
    height: px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
#userInfo {
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: right;
    border: 0px dashed black;
    padding: px;
    height: 37px;
    Width: 250px;
}
#leftcolumn {
    color: black;
    background: url('images/left_panel.jpg') no-repeat;
    padding: 6px;
    height: 615px;
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#leftSide {
    clear: both;
    color: black;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 604px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-right: 2px groove #8d8d8d;
}
#rightSide {
    color: #114064;
    padding: 6px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 280px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 0px solid black;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 350px;
}
.loginT {
    background: #e3f1fb;
    color: #114064;
    border: 1px groove #114064;
}
.tipText {
    font-size: 13px;
}
}
.loginT1 {
    background: #9da6ad;
    color: #114064;
    border: 1px groove #114064;
    width: 200px;
}
.loginB {
    background: url('images/login.jpg') no-repeat;
    width: 57px;
    height: 25px;
    border: 0px;
}
#regDiv {
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: black;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 630px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#videoDiv {
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    width: 520px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: url('images/videoDiv_l.jpg') no-repeat;
}
#videoDiv h2 {
    font-size: 12pt;
}
#videoDiv p {
    color: white;
    font-size: 12pt;
}
}
#homeBottom {
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px;
    width: 890px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#content {
    float: left;
    color: black;
    background:url('images/main_column.jpg') 0px -41px no-repeat;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:15px;
    height: 610px;
    width: 225px;
    display: inline;
}
#rightcolumn {
    color: black;
    background:url('images/main_column.jpg') 0px -41px no-repeat;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:6px;
    height: 610px;
    width: 240px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
#footer {
    background:url('images/footer.jpg') top no-repeat;
    height:50px;
    width: 940px;
    margin-top: 750px;
    margin-left: -12px;
}
#aaFooter {
    background:url('images/footer.jpg') top no-repeat;
    height:50px;
    width: 930px;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
#reg_footer {
    background:url('images/footer.jpg') no-repeat;
    height:39px;
    width: 940px;
    margin-top: 700px;
    margin-left: -13px;
    border: 0px solid black;
}
#home_footer {
    clear:both;
    /*background:url('images/home_footer.png') top no-repeat;*/
    
    height:290px;
    width: 940px;
    margin-top: 400px;
    margin-left: -9px;
}
.buttonTop {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background:url('images/home_footer.jpg');
}
.hidden {
    /*visibility:hidden; */
    
    display: none;
}
td {
    font-size: 13px;
}
/* Background Image for text boxes */

.tb0 {
    background-image: url(images/tbbg2.jpg);
    border: 1px solid #6297BC;
    width: 200px;
}
.btn {
    background-image: url(images/tbbg2.jpg);
    border: 1px solid #6297BC;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.lph {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 12px;
    width: 280px;
    float: left;
}
.tb4 {
    background-image: url(images/tbbg2.jpg);
    border: 1px solid #6297BC;
    width: 70px;
    font-family: Myriad Pro,
    Arial,
    Helvetica,
    sans-serif;
    /*text-align: right;*/
}
.tb5 {
    background-image: url(images/tbbg2.jpg);
    border: 0px solid #6297BC;
}
.disabled {
    background-color: #d3e7f5;
    color: black;
    font-family: Myriad Pro,
    Arial,
    Helvetica,
    sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: 50px;
    display: block;
}
#hdg {
    position: absolute;
    background:;
    padding: 0px;
}
#genericCenterDiv {
    background: white;
    height: 400px;
}
#topTip {
    height: px;
    width: 910px;
    background:#98a9fd;
    padding: 5px;
    display:none;
    color: white;
}
.help {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: orange;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.infoImg {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    border:none;
}
a:visited img {
    border: 0px;
}
a:visited {
    color:gray;
}
.inputTable {} .related {
    /*
background: url('images/linkBg.png') no-repeat;
*/
}
.up {
    color: black;
    background: url('images/upBg.jpg') no-repeat;
    font-family: Myriad Pro,
    Arial,
    Helvetica,
    sans-serif;
    /*border: 2px solid #36db30;*/
    
    width: 50px;
}
.down {
    color: black;
    background: url('images/downBg.jpg') no-repeat;
    font-family: Myriad Pro,
    Arial,
    Helvetica,
    sans-serif;
    /*border: 2px solid red;*/
    
    width: 50px;
}
.noChangeInput {
    border: 3px solid black;
}
td {} .invisible {
    visibility:hidden;
}
a:active {
    outline: none;
}
.rowDiv {
    width: 235px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 0px solid navy;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right:5px;
    border-bottom:0px solid #e1e2e4;
}
.rowDiv2 {
    width: 290px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 0px solid navy;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    border-bottom:0px solid #e1e2e4;
}
.rowDivGridlines {
    border-bottom:1px solid #e1e2e4;
}
.inputDiv {
    float: right;
}
div.htmltooltip {
    position: absolute;
    /*leave this and next 3 values alone*/
    
    z-index: 1000;
    left: -5000px;
    top: -5000px;
    /*background: #272727; */
    
    background-image: url(images/tbbg2.jpg);
    border: 2px groove #195e93;
    color:1a1d20;
    padding: 3px;
    font-family: Myriad Pro,
    Arial,
    Helvetica,
    sans-serif;
    width: 250px;
    /*width of tooltip*/
}
.trS {
    background: yellow;
}
a.footerLink {
    font-family: Myriad Pro,
    Arial,
    Helvetica,
    sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
}
.checkbox,
.radio {
    width: 19px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    background: url(checkbox.gif) no-repeat;
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    float: left;
}
.exerciseColumn {
    float:left;
    margin-left:1px;
}
.relatedOutput {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border:1px #000066 solid;
}
.relatedInput {
    border:1px #000066 solid;
}
.outputHigher {
    color: black;
    background-color:#99FF99;
    /* background: url('images/upBg.png') no-repeat;*/
    
    font-family: Myriad Pro,
    Arial,
    Helvetica,
    sans-serif;
    /*border: 2px solid #36db30;*/
    
    width: 50px;
}
.outputLower {
    color: black;
    /*background: url('images/downBg.png') no-repeat;*/
    
    background-color:#ff9999;
    font-family: Myriad Pro,
    Arial,
    Helvetica,
    sans-serif;
    /*border: 2px solid red;*/
    
    width: 50px;
}
.outputUnchanged {
    background-color:#d0d0d0;
}
.inputdiv {
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
}
.inputControlLeft {
    float:left;
}
.inputControlRight {
    float:right;
}
.inputControl {
    text-align:right;
    height:16px;
}
.outputdiv {
    height:21px;
    width:100%;
}
.outputControlLeft {
    float:left;
}
.outputControlRight {
    float:right;
    padding-top:1px;
}
.outputControl {
    text-align:right;
    height:16px;
    border:none;
}
#divInputs {
    margin-top:10px;
}
.divunit {
    width:10px;
    float:right;
    font-size:10px;
}
.divcurrency {
    width:8px;
    float:right;
    font-size:12px;
}
.spacerline {
    height:1px;
    background-color:DarkGray;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
.tooltip {
    width:300px;
    opacity:1.0;
}
.mainmenuitem {} .menuIcon {
    padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
}
img.menuIcon:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.tabIcon {
    padding: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.menuButton {
    position:relative;
    left:30px;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:60px;
    border:2px solid #044B79;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-right:5px;
    font-size:9pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color:#5788B1;
    color:#e8e8e8;
    text-align:center;
}
.homepagecol .menuButton {
    width:100px;
    height:35px;
    float:none;
}
.xxx .homepagecol .menuButton:first-letter {
    color:blue;
}
.FL1 {
    color:#5788B1;
}
.FL2 {
    color:#6DB44E;
}
.FL3 {
    color:#044B79;
}
.FLG {
    color:#505050;
}
.menuButton:hover {
    /*background-color:DarkGray;*/
    
    background-color:#6DB44E;
}
.menuButton_Selected {
    background-color:lightgray;
}
#assessortabs {
    height:109px;
    font-size:8pt;
}
#mainmenu_left {
    display:block;
    width:250px;
    float:left;
}
#mainmenu {
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
#tutorButton {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0px;
    /*background:url('images/tutor.png'); */
    
    border: 0px solid red;
    width: 61px;
    height: 78px;
}
.tutorButton_on {
    background:url('images/tutor_on.jpg');
}
.tutorButton_off {
    background:url('images/tutor.jpg');
}
#resourcesButton {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 3px;
    background:url('images/resources.jpg');
    border: 0px solid red;
    width: 61px;
    height: 78px;
}
#dlgCaseStudy {
    width:550px;
}
.fldialog {
    width:500px;
    font-size:12px;
    display:none;
}
.fldialog h3 {
    font-weight:bold;
}
.fldialog select {
    width:200px;
}
.fldialog a {
    color:#0000aa;
}
.footercolumn {
    float:left;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    width:30%;
    color: #3b4750;
}
.footercolumn h2 {
    padding: 4px;
}
.ItsEasy {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 330px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 23px;
    margin-right:50px;
}
.ItsEasy li {
    margin:5px;
}
#outputtabs {
    font-size:11px;
}
#inputtabs {
    font-size:11px;
}
#mainChart {
    width:400px;
    height:250px;
}
.homepagecol {
    font-family:Tahoma;
    float:left;
    width:16%;
    padding:8px;
    text-align:center;
}
.homepagecol h1 {
    font-size:12pt;
}
.homepagecol h2 {
    font-size:12px;
    padding:10px;
}
#learningtips {
    width:250px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:lightgray;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:5px;
}
#learningtips h1 {
    font-size:12pt;
}
#graphs {
    height:400px;
}
.graphSelect {} #graphselect {
    padding-top:10px;
}
#graphselectleft {
    width:45%;
    float:left;
}
#graphselectcenter {
    width:20%;
    float:left;
}
#graphselectright {
    width:30%;
    float:left;
}
#exerciseheader {
    height:150px;
    padding-top:8px;
    margin-left:4px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
#exercisequestion {
    width:48%;
    float:left;
}
#exerciseanswer {
    width:48%;
    float:left;
}
.goal {
    background-color:lightblue;
}
#exercisehelp {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:17px;
}
#exercisehelp li {
    padding-top:3px;
}
#selItemsToGraph {
    width:150px;
}
.flhelp {
    width:400px;
    height:300px;
    display:none;
}
#dlgHelpLeft {
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    border:1px solid darkgray;
}
#dlgHelpDetails {
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    font-size:8pt;
    padding:3px;
    border:1px solid darkgray;
}
#dlgHelpDebug {
    margin-left:10px;
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    font-size:8pt;
    padding:3px;
    border:1px solid darkgray;
}
#dlgHelpDetails h1 {
    font-size:10pt;
}
#dlgHelpDetails h2 {
    font-size:9pt;
}
#dlgHelpSearchResults h1 {
    font-size:10pt;
}
#dlgHelpDetails p {
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
#dlgHelpDetails a {
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#dlgHelpDetails textarea {
    font-size:9pt;
}
#dlgHelpDetails input {
    font-size:9pt;
}
.helplink {
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.calc {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-size:10pt;
}
.helphighlight {
    background-color:yellow;
}
#dlgHelpDetails ul {
    padding-left:15px;
}
#dlgHelpSearch {
    width:100%;
}
#dlgHelpSearchEntry {
    float:left;
    width:25%;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#dlgHelpSearchResults {
    padding-left:2px;
    float:left;
    width:85%;
    border:1px solid darkgray;
}
#selHelp {
    width:100%;
}
#dlgHelpAddItem {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is with the CSS not showing up so showing us what you wrote won't help solve the problem. The problem will lie with your server and how you have that set up. In addition, showing what you want doesn't tell us what you see.

Comment: Oh Okay, but it is set up the same as it alway has been.

Comment: Can you link your website or the details from your html page that isn't working?

Comment: http://www.fabeducation.com/registerChoice.php this is one of the pages